# Prompt() Function/Method vs User Made Function

Tags: javascript

When I store a function that I made in a variable I get an error. Why does this happen? I've written the function before the variables and this still happens. I know that the JavaScript interpreter reads the code then runs it if it doesnt find any errors.

```js
let upper = 10000 ;
let getRandomNumber = getRandomNumber(upper) ;
let guess ;
let guessAttempts = 0 ;

function getRandomNumber(upper) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * upper) + 1 ;
}
```

Comment: Didn't quite get your question.  The above snippet throws: `"message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'getRandomNumber' has already been declared",`

Comment: Because you try to create a function with a name that is already used for a variable.

Comment: This is on hold unreasonably. The question is not "unclear" at all. The OP could have learnt something here.

Comment: @Muhammad JS hoist functions first. Now when you try to create a function expression with the same name, the compiler complains!

Comment: @Charlie The first sentence is very unclear, it's unclear what `prompt` has to do with anything, there's no explicit error message mentioned (though arguably it's easy to reproduce if you care to), and even if we ignore all that, the problem has been answered in the comments and in an answer and syntax errors in general aren't terribly helpful. If you rewrote the question so it would very clearly explain the problem and might enable future visitors to find it via a search, then it may serve some purpose.

Comment: @CharlieH thank you so much for the explaining! I hadnt noticed that i named the function and the variable the same.

Comment: @Seblor ok, thank you for the help!

Comment: @Sid i named the function and a variable the same and that caused the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the variable name same as the function name. That causes error. Change the name of the variable.

```
let upper = 10000 ;
let RandomNumber = getRandomNumber(upper) ;
let guess ;
let guessAttempts = 0 ;

function getRandomNumber(upper) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * upper) + 1 ;
}
```